# Raspberry Pi Zero -V1.3 Kali-SSH VNC through USB connected to PC possible?

Tags: ssh, pi-zero, vnc, kali

I would like to SSH and VNC to a rasberry pi Zero V1.3 (Non-wifi) running Kali using just the USB connected to a Ubuntu that is connected to the network.

It is possible with Raspbian:
https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/06/connect-raspberry-pi-zero-usb-cable-ssh/

I have a Pi Zero - W that connects to my wifi router.  I have it setup with Kali the way I like.  I backed it up, then used that backup for a new SD card for the pi Zero -V1.3.  It boots up fine.

I just can't find any info on the internet on how to do this.

Comment: so, this is a pi 1? not a 0? if so, then no. Only pi ZERO can do the gadget mode thing as far as I'm aware

Comment: It is a pi-Zero.  The one released before the pi-zero-W

Comment: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2885

Comment: oh, well that should be fine then - of course, Kali probably doesn't have ALL the goodies that raspbian does

Comment: https://blog.gbaman.info/?p=791

Comment: I also had the same problem with the USB-network only working over IPv6 on Ubuntu 14.04, but I figured out how to also get it working over IPv4, which ‘fixes’ raspberrypi.local 

You need to go into the network-manager menu, Edit Connections… and edit the new Ethernet connection (for me it was “Wired connection 2”). Switch to the IPv4 tab, and change the Method to “Link-Local only”. Click Save and then Close.

The usb0 network interface will then get assigned a 169.254.x.y address, and “ssh pi@raspberrypi.local” will work just like it should.